# How to concat previous text with new one in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, concatenation

i have a Text using as a Label named 'lblPlo' and want to show text entered in TextInput (txtPlo) without losing the previous text, like if i enter '1' in Textinput (txtPlo) and press the button the text in 'lblPlo' should be "1" and again if i enter '4' it should be "1,4". Kindly help. here is my code for the button pressed.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            txtPlo: '',
            lblPlo: '',
        }
    }

     addBtnPressed = () => { 
        var result = this.state.txtPlo.concat(" ", this.state.lblPlo);
        this.setState({ SampleText: result });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
addBtnPressed = () => { 

this.setState(prevState=>{
...prevState,
lblPlo : prevState.lblPlo.concat(" , " + prevState.txtPlo)
}, ()=>console.log("updated label: ", this.state.lblPlo));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually it was my bad... i was trying to concat empty string again and again the following modification worked for me. just replaced lblPlo with SampleText.

```
    constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                txtPlo: '',
               SampleText: '',
            }
        }

        addBtnPressed = () => {
            var result = this.state.SampleText.concat(" ", this.state.txtPlo);
            this.setState({ SampleText: result });
        }
```